# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for Error, please help me spot it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been trying to follow the [Active Record Nested Attributes Guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), without much success.

I have the following models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :telephones
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :telephones
end

class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

When trying to create a contact:

```
contact = {
  :name => "John",
  :telephones => [
    {:telephone => '787445741'},
    {:telephone => '478589658'}
  ]
}
Contact.create(contact)
```

I get the following error:
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Telephone(#80827590) expected, got Hash(#72886250)`

Could you please help me spot the error?
Is there any code that I should include in the `contact_controller.rb`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working with the following code:

```
params = { :contact => {
    :name => 'Joe',
    :permanentcomment => "No Comment",
    :telephones_attributes => [
      {:telephone => '787445741'},
      {:telephone => '478589658'}
    ]
  }}
  Contact.create(params[:contact])
```

I was passing the wrong arguments to the `Contact.create` controller...